# sublime symlink disappeared after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: sublimetext3, alias, zshrc, osx-elcapitan

I have just upgraded to OS X El Capitan and `subl .` command stopped working with the `zsh: command not found: subl` error message.

I have run the following command as suggested in other posts:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

result:

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
```

in the **".bash_profile"** as well as **".zsh_profile"** I have the following lines saved:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

Also tried:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

result:

```
ln: /usr/bin/subl: Operation not permitted
```

Update:
it seemed to work after running the following command:

```
alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
```

but as soon as I restart the terminal, `subl .` command stops working.

Update2:
after pasting the following line: `alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"` in the `subl ~/.zshrc`,  `subl .` command works even after restarting the terminal, but terminal seems to work slower than normal, and when you open relatively small folders with `subl .` command, at times it's taking ages to show the files...

Final Update:
After running `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl` followed by 
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl` **everything works perfectly**, thanks to **@chris**.

Comment: Are you sure the .bash_profile is read by `zsh`?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know that, but I have the same lines inside the zsh_profile

Comment: Ok. Type `echo $PATH` on the command line to see if /usr/local/bin is in your path variable.

Comment: @lenz,  typed `echo $PATH` result:
`/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/anvarturobov/.rbenv/shims:/Users/anvarturobov/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In El Capitan, you are not allowed to write to `/usr/bin`, but writing to `/usr/local/bin` is ok. By default, `/usr/local/bin` should also be in your path variable.

Had the same issue. Deleting and recreating the symlink has fixed the problem. Perhaps the current symlink is pointing to the wrong location after the upgrade.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Or **Sublime Text 2** (from – @simen comment):

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Comment: Thanks @chris, it worked. I've removed `export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH`
`export EDITOR='subl -w'` from **".bash_profile"** as well as `alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'" ` from the  the `subl ~/.zshrc`. Everything works well so far. Thank you.

Comment: Remember to add "\ 2" if you're using Sublime Text 2: ```sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl```

Comment: Didn't have to do the `rm` step because it didn't exist, but otherwise perfect solution for me. Thank you.